# Image Slider is not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my webpage there is supposed to be an image slider (carousel). My one problem is, it's not loading correctly. As you can see on my site there are 4 bullet points and 4 images next to them. Could you see if i am missing anything in terms of my files being incorrect? I will also add a link to the site where you can find my image slider, and i also added a link to my site to help on your end.

-Thanks!

My site: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

ImageSlider: http://bxslider.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript to init the bxSlider isn't working, it looks like you may have an errant "style" tag or something (it's trying to close a style block, the body, and the html all within your script), also make sure to include type="text/javascript" in your  tag, and finally it's usually safest to do you jQuery onLoad functions like so:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(...).blahblah();
});
```

Then "$" will be scoped a bit better.

Comment: For the first answer with the init what exactly do i need to do? I am kindof a beginner. For the second answer is this right? : <script type="text/javascript src="myscripts.js"></script>. and for the last answer is this also right? : jQuery(function($){
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
                });

Comment: For the above that i have edited i kept everything in the same place as it was when you looked at it.

Comment: @Alex Question #2 and #3 look perfect to me except it should be <script type="text/javascript"...></script> (just close the quote on the type). For the first answer, I can't be sure but I'd look in your html where you actually set up that <script> block, my guess is that you accidentally have a </style> to close it rather than a </script>? If you inspect the source of that page you sent, you can see the weirdness at the bottom.

Comment: @Alex sorry I should be a bit more specific as well, the script that I'm referring to is at the bottom of the html, right after the bootstrap.js file is included

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are using

`<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

before loading jquery. 
Please always use jquery scripts after loading jquery.min.js

also try to load the

`<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>`

after bootstrap.js